# Transposing and inserting cells at the same time

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble with the following problem. I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
1  3  4  6  7
1  2
2  4  5  9
5  
1  2  3  5
```

I want to take the single numbers common in each, and arrange them in one column:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
9
```

The approach I'm taking for a script to recognise that there is more than one complete cell in a row, then execute a command to transpose the adjacent cells beneath the current range. What I have so far is:

```
Sub RecordArrangeTest()
Dim Rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim n As Long
Dim Wholecolumn As Range
Dim Lastcolumn As Long
Lastcolumn = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
i = 1

Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).row

While i <= lastRow
Set Rng = Range("A" & i)
Set Wholecolumn = Range(Cells(i, i), Cells(1, Lastcolumn))
If IsEmpty(Rng.Offset(0, 1).Value) = False Then
Range(Rng.Offset(1, 0), Rng.Offset(Lastcolumn, 0)).Insert Shift:=xlDown
Wholecolumn.Copy
Rng.Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
Wholecolumn.Delete Shift:=xlUp
i = i + 1
Else: i = i + 1

End If
Wend

End Sub
```

Although during testing, this works well for i = 1, increasing i after the first trigger causes a mistmatch somewhere. Is there anything I'm missing? Or is there a different approach you'd recommend instead?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a dictionary that ignores duplicates and iterate through all the used cells, then clear the entire range and paste the dictionary back in its place.

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
Dim rng As Range
Dim t
Dim i As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

For Each rng In ws.UsedRange
    If rng <> "" Then
        On Error Resume Next
            dict.Add rng.Value, rng.Value
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
Next rng

ws.UsedRange.ClearContents
i = 1
For Each t In dict
    ws.Cells(i, "A").Value = t
    i = i + 1
Next t

ws.Range("A1:A" & i).Sort key1:=ws.Range("A1")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm getting a compile error for "Set Dict" first. Do I need a Dim line first?

Comment: It work as is for me, you can try adding a `Dim dict As Object` before. @user1996971

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps not your solution, but Power Query (Get & Transform) will work. With source data in a 5 column table called "Table1", paste this into the Advanced Editor in Power Query:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column1", Int64.Type}, {"Column2", Int64.Type}, {"Column3", Int64.Type}, {"Column4", Int64.Type}, {"Column5", type any}}),

    #"Col1" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Column1"}),
    #"Rename1" = Table.RenameColumns(Col1,{{"Column1", "ColumnName"}}),

    #"Col2" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Column2"}),
    #"Rename2" = Table.RenameColumns(Col2,{{"Column2", "ColumnName"}}),

    #"Col3" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Column3"}),
    #"Rename3" = Table.RenameColumns(Col3,{{"Column3", "ColumnName"}}),

    #"Col4" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Column4"}),
    #"Rename4" = Table.RenameColumns(Col4,{{"Column4", "ColumnName"}}),

    #"Col5" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Changed Type",{"Column5"}),
    #"Rename5" = Table.RenameColumns(Col5,{{"Column5", "ColumnName"}}),

    #"AppendQueries" = Table.Combine({Rename1,Rename2,Rename3,Rename4,Rename5}),

    #"RemoveDuplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"AppendQueries"),
    #"SortRows" = Table.Sort(#"RemoveDuplicates",{{"ColumnName", Order.Ascending}})
in
    #"SortRows"
```